# How can i display stringBuilder objects as well as Arraystring in alert box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

when we store more than one string in arraystring or in stringbuilder class objects.then how can we print it on alert box in asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (register client script needs more parameters im sure).

```
Dim _script as String = String.Concat("<script type='javascript'>", _stringBuilder.ToString(), "</script>")
Page.RegisterClientScript(_script)
```